# Hide decimals on Prestashop

Tags: decimal, prestashop

I´m working with **Prestashop** and I´m displaying prices with **4 decimals** because I´m accepting EUR and Bitcoins. This is the code where the price is loaded:

```
<span class="price"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
```

Is it possible to set the **last 2 decimals** to display:none?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Prestashop you should be editing a TPL file. If that's correct you should not use echo inside TPL. You can use this function:

```
<span class="price">{convertPrice price=$product.price}</span>
```

Or just use `round` PHP function and specify decimal precision:

```
<span class="price">{round($product.price, 2)}</span>
```

In javascript you can use `Math.round()` function. More info here: [Round 2 decimals JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places)
There is no way to hide decimals partially.

Good luck.

Comment: Is it a way to do it in javascript? Some function where I can say something like: "Set style="display:none" to the numbers after the second decimal"

Answer (score 0):

There is a module in PrestaShop Addons, so you can define decimals by currency. For example, you can define 2 decimals for EUR and 4 decimals for Bitcoins.

The link of the module in the Addons :

https://addons.prestashop.com/en/price-management/28731-number-of-decimals-for-price-by-currency.html